# Duplicate class com.android.volley found in modules (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0

Tags: android, android-volley

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ariacloud.monaria"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        configurations { all*.exclude module: 'volley-release' }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    def recyclerview_version = "1.0.0"

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"
    // For control over item selection of both touch and mouse driven selection
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:$recyclerview_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
     implementation 'devlight.io:navigationtabbar:1.2.5'
   // implementation 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabbar:library:1.1.2'
    //compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:15.0.0'
    //implementation files('libs/volley.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### here is the error :

Duplicate class com.android.volley.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Cache found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Cache$Entry found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher$1 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$1 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Network found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.NetworkResponse found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Request found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Request$1 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Request$Method found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Request$Priority found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RequestQueue found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$1 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$RequestFilter found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$RequestFinishedListener found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Response found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Response$ErrorListener found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Response$Listener found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ResponseDelivery found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RetryPolicy found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.VolleyLog found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.VolleyLog$MarkerLog found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.VolleyLog$MarkerLog$Marker found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.AndroidAuthenticator found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.Authenticator found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ByteArrayPool found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ByteArrayPool$1 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack$HttpPatch found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack$UrlRewriter found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$1 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$2 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$3 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$4 found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$BatchedImageRequest found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$ImageContainer found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$ImageListener found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.PoolingByteArrayOutputStream found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley found in modules jetified-volleyplus-0.1.4-runtime.jar (dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4) and volley-1.1.0-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have two dependencies regarding volley that are colliding because both of them have same class:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
```

You will just need one as it says here: https://developer.android.com/training/volley

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

So, just remove implementation 'dev.dworks...'

Comment: yes but when i remove dev.dwork it says StringRequest is missing in volley class. do you know about full volley that contain all classes?

Comment: I guess you are following a tutorial that use that library and that's why you are trying to use StringRequest which depends on that library. As the version of that lib is 0.1.4 i would recommend not to use it because the version is not formally released (as version 1.0.0 for example). So you can 1- Find another tutorial using pure volley and not that lib. 2- Try to put only dworks library removing the other as the library should be implementing volley already.

Comment: on course i am following a tuto , how do u know ?ok thanks i will try

Comment: for me the volley:1.1.0 is used in another dependency. How do I fix that? 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63926767/1397821

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:+
```

to replace with

```
 implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
```